# Submitted form won't change the values in the database

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have a DATABASE with users and their emails, but can't add new users from the code. I have a form located in C:\xampp\htdocs but when try to add a user through the form, nothing happens. I can only make changes in pma.

```html
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=misc', 
   'fred', 'zap');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


<?php
require_once "pdo.php";

if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($POST['email']) 
  && isset($_POST['password'])) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password)
    VALUES (:name, :email, :password)"; 
  echo("<pre>\n".$sql."\n</pre>\n");
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
  $stmt->execute(array(
   ':name' => $_POST['name'],
   ':email' => $_POST['email'],
   ':password' => $_POST['password']));
  
}
?>
<html>
<head></head><body>
<p>Add a New User</p>
<form method="post">
 <p>Name:
 <input type="text" name="name" size="40"></p>
 <p>Email:
 <input type="text" name="email"></p>
 <p>Password:
 <input type="password" name="email"</p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Add New"/></p>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you have you opening php tags? You should remove second tag <?php

Comment: isset($POST['email'] missing a _

Comment: Your HTML contains errors.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the `<input type="password" name="email"`. Here the `name='password'` instead of `name="email"`.

`isset($_POST['password']))` return null and if condition is unsatisfied so the query doesn't execute>

Comment: The password input should use name="password" not name="email"

Answer (score -1):

Try this code below.

```
 <?php
    //require_once "pdo.php";

    //my own db connection
    $pdo = new PDO (
        'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=misc;charset=utf8', 
        'fred', // username

        'zap' // password
    );


    if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($POST['email']) 
         && isset($_POST['password'])) {


    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, password) 
    values(:name, :email, :password) ");
    $sql->execute(array( 

    ':name' => $_POST['name'],
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':password' => $_POST['password']

    ));
    if(sql){
    echo "success"; 
}else{
echo "failed";
}       
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head></head><body>
    <p>Add a New User</p>
    <form method="post">
        <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40"></p>
        <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></p>
        <p>Password:
        <input type="password" name="password"  id="password"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Add New"></p>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Didnt downvote but here it is `isset($POST['email']`